# Firebase System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting the error System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled when trying to any user admin operation on Firebase, using C# SDK.

Here is an example of how I am doing the call to Firebase Admin:

```
public static async Task<bool> SaveUserInFirebaseAsync(string email, string nome, bool emailVerified, string password, Guid uid)
{
    UserRecordArgs args = new UserRecordArgs()
    {
        Uid = uid.ToString().ToUpper(),
        Email = email,
        EmailVerified = emailVerified,
        DisplayName = nome,
        Password = password
    };
    try
    {
        UserRecord userRecord = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync(args);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.startFileLog(ex.ToString(), null, null, null, LogType.Error);
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I dont know if its a firebase error or if I am doing the async call wrong.

Edit:

Here is the full stack trace

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__59.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.<SendAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.<SendAndReadAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Util.ErrorHandlingHttpClient`1.<SendAndDeserializeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Auth.Users.FirebaseUserManager.<PostAndDeserializeAsync>d__29`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Auth.Users.FirebaseUserManager.<GetUserAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Auth.Users.FirebaseUserManager.<GetUserByEmailAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth.<GetUserByEmailAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at FirebaseAdmin.Auth.AbstractFirebaseAuth.<GetUserByEmailAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at TeltonikaSiteWebApplication.WebApplicationHelpers.FireBaseHelper.<SaveUserInFirebaseAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Check for any inner exception, that will have more information.

Comment: @Gusman I've updated the question to include a full stack trace.

Comment: A stack trace is not an inner exception. Check if there is an inner exception.

Comment: @Gusman sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Any solution on this?!